# Find the no of substrings a character is part of

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

I am looking for a O(1) solution for *finding the number of substrings a character is part of.*

For instance, let `s = "abcde"` and all substrings of s are
`a, b, c, d, e, ab, bc, cd, de, abc, bcd, cde, abcd, bcde, abcde`

Now 'a' is part of `a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde`
So I guess The first (and the last character) of the string is part of 5 or in general `len(s)` substrings

'b' is part of `b, ab, bc, abc, bcd, abcd, bcde, abcde`, 8 substrings
'c' is part of `c, bc, cd, abc, bcd, cde, abcd, bcde, abcde`, 9 substrings

So in general how do I find the no of substrings a character in part of ?
also assume all characters are distinct.

Edit:
What I have tried so far.

Total number of substring ?
`n * (n + 1) / 2`, where n = len(s)

Number of substring that start with the given letter ?
I guess its `len(s) - i`, where 'i' is the index (0 based indexing) of given letter ?

Also it looks like the closer a letter is to len(s) / 2, the higher its substing count

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a straightforward counting argument.  Can you count how many substrings there are in the string, total?  Can you count how many substrings start with the given letter?  What progress have you made on this task?

Comment: Can you clarify on whether the original string will always have distinct characters, or are repeats allowed?

Comment: @D.W. I have added what I have tried / found so far

Comment: @JimN Assume all characters are distinct

Comment: 'c' is part of 'b' ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust my bad, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your length-5 string, your indices are $0,1,2,3,4$.

Take a character like $b$ of index 1. It will be in every substring defined by $(i,j)$ where $i$ can be $0,1$ and $j$ can be any of $1,2,3,4$. Can you see why the answer for $b$ is 8 without having the write them all out?

Take character $c$ at position index 2. It will be in every substring starting at index $i=0,1,2$ and ending at index $j=2,3,4$. Can you see why your answer for $c$ is 9 without having to write them all out?

Comment: Ok I got it now,  thanks